# MEF: ComposeParts missing

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I am trying to follow some starter guides for using MEF in .Net 4, but I get stuck when I get to setting up the application. The instructions say to do this:

```
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@".\");
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
container.Composeparts(this);
```

But the version of System.ComponentModel.Composition included with .Net 4 doesn't seem to have the Composeparts method available on CompositionContainer, and I am unable to find a good reference on how to do this in the current system.

Here is the reference I am currently using:
[Building Composable Apps in .NET 4 with the Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291628.aspx)

Does anyone out there have a better reference that I should be looking at?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The CompositionContainer does have a ComposeParts method, as an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.attributedmodelservices.composeparts.aspx).

See [this](http://web1.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MEFIntroduction.aspx) reference for some working code.

Comment: why oh why oh why is it an extension method! thanks for the answer :-)

Answer (score 22):

One thing to note, if you haven't used extension methods before. You MUST have the using statement. In this case:

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
```

for the code in the question to work. Without the using statement, the intellisense and compiler will not allow the use of the extension method.

Comment: Thanks. You saved me valuable minutes at a Hackathon.